# Set MinDate Datepicker with Materialize by two input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, materialize

How to set minDate in second input refer by first input?
my HTML

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="from">
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="to">
```

My JS

```
$('#from').datepicker({
  autoClose : true,
  format : 'dd mmm yyyy',
  minDate : new Date(),
$("#to").datepicker({
  autoClose : true,
  format : 'dd mmm yyyy',
  minDate: new Date()
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/rt9780xs/16/
I just using materialize and jQuery. Anybody help? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I got some old code for this one. Maybe this is what are you looking for.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.calendar_max_min = function(){

var ths = $(this);
var caltarget = ths.data("target");
var calcheck = ths.data("calcheck");
var calmin  = (ths.data("type") === "min") ? '' : $(caltarget+"[data-type='min']").prop("value");
var calmax  = (ths.data("type") === "max") ? '' : $(caltarget+"[data-type='max']").prop("value");

     if(!calcheck){
       ths.attr("data-calcheck","true");
       ths.datepicker({
       format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
       startDate: calmin,
       endDate: calmax
            });
        ths.datepicker("show");
     }else{
        ths.datepicker("destroy");
       ths.datepicker({
       format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
       startDate: calmin,
       endDate: calmax
            });
        ths.datepicker("show");
     }
};

$(".my_calendar, .my_calendar2").on("click",$.calendar_max_min);

});
```

Try check this JSFiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/synz/g2yohfb6/

Comment: yes in your code was work, is possible if I use materialize? I still difficult to create by materialize based on documentation

Comment: Yes you can. check this for materialize https://jsfiddle.net/synz/as5f901b/